# Why am I getting TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined error in google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am just trying to bold the first column data in the sheet.

```
function formatColumnHeader(){
var thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var dataRange = thisSheet.getDataRange();
var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();

for(var row =1;row<dataValues.length;row++){
 dataRange[row][0].setFontWeight('bold');
}
}
```

But I get TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It looks odd that you are using `dataValues.length` in the condition of the for-loop, but are accessing `dataRange`. Did you mean `dataValues[row][0]`?

Comment: Yea well, setFontWeight() is the method of Range object, and dataValues is a 2D array.
I found my mistake and corrected,
I did mean `dataValues[row][0]` but the setFontWeight method can be applied to range object only, so I did the following
`function formatColumnHeader(){
  var thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = thisSheet.getDataRange();
  var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();

  for(var row =1;row<dataValues.length;row++){

    var columnHeader = thisSheet.getRange(row,1)
 
    columnHeader.setFontWeight('bold');
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`range.offset`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset,-numrows,-numcolumns):

```
function formatColumnHeader(){
  const thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
    dataRange = thisSheet.getDataRange();
  dataRange.offset(0, 0, dataRange.getNumRows(), 1).setFontWeight('bold');
}
```

Or if you have no need for `dataRange`, try `getRange()` to get only the range that you need:

```
function formatColumnHeader(){
  const thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  dataRange = thisSheet.getRange(1, 1, thisSheet.getLastRow()).setFontWeight('bold');
}
```